# Incompatibility between Fragment and ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

**Note**
: I've looked at questions similar to this. Most of them said to interchange between `import android.app.ListFragment` and `import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`; However this didn't solve my problem.

I've made a `Fragment` called `fragmentOne`. I've tried to implement a list in `fragmentOne` using `ListFragment`.  When a particular button is clicked, `FragmentOne` should appear on screen. The method to be called when the button for `fragmentOne` is pressed, is `FragmentOneClick(View v)`. It is in `MainActivity.java`.  However, in this method, in the line:

```
  Fragment myFragment=new fragmentTwo();
```

I'm getting an error saying:

> incompatible types. Required : android.app.ListFragment
>   found: com.example.projectName.fragmentOne

How can I resolve this error?

`fragmentOne.java`:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class fragmentOne extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    String dates[]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView;
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dates);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.fragmentOne">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void FragmentOneClick(View v)
    {
        ListFragment myFragment=new fragmentOne();
        FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, (android.app.Fragment) myFragment );
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void FragmentTwoClick(View v)
    {
        Fragment myFragment=new fragmentTwo();
        FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, myFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:onClick="FragmentOneClick"
    android:text="Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    </Button>

<Button
    android:text="Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="FragmentTwoClick"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fragment_switch"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fragment_switch">
    android:layout_weight="2"
</Button>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_switch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:name="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.fragmentOne"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is fragmentTwo

Comment: @rahul kapoor fragmentTwo doesnt do anything. That's why I've not mentioned the code for it.

Comment: From which class you derived fragmentTwo?

Comment: @rahul kapoor   from Fragment

Comment: Join this https://join.skype.com/HGid6ntbIZhk